# First echo database row doesn't show PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I have this problem that the first row from the database doesn't show. 
Here is how it looks like:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("xxxxxx","xxxxxxx","","xxxxxxx");
    $sql="SELECT* from flyreise";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";

$countRows=mysqli_affected_rows($db);
    for($i=0;$i<$countRows;$i++){
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<td><strong>From:</strong>".$row["fra"]." <br><strong>To:</strong> ".$row["til"]." <br><strong>Date:</strong> ".$row["dato"]." <br><strong>Clock:</strong> ".$row["klokkeslett"]."</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
      }

echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: check for Errors after executing SQL statements

Comment: Maybe you have an empty row in your database?

Comment: Looks more like the last row, not the first. Try `var_dump($row);` to see if it shows anything. Additionally, instead of using `mysqli_affected_rows` and `for($i=0;$i<$countRows;$i++)`, it might be better to change the loop to use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` instead.

Comment: @aynber I tried that, but then it just hide the last row and the bold text that you see. I know I have 6 rows in the database, but it just shows 5 now.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the database? Determine exactly which row is missing.

Comment: use this $countRows=mysqli_affected_rows($result);

Comment: Your coding attempt is glaring proof that you did not refer to the php manual before posting. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php  You aren't meant to check for affected rows from a SELECT query and you don't need the row count either.  You would be better tocall `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` for your needs.  Also, your html table structure is broken -- you have 1 table heading cell and your table body has 3 columns.  If you were following a tutorial/video, you should find another one.

Comment: Correction, you don't have 3 columns in the table body, you have _n_ * 3 columns in a single row.  This design needs a rethink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `for` loop with this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<td><strong>From:</strong>".$row["fra"]." <br><strong>To:</strong> 
    ".$row["til"]." <br><strong>Date:</strong> ".$row["dato"]." <br><strong>Clock: 
   </strong> ".$row["klokkeslett"]."</td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
}
```

You are telling you program to keep looping through `mysql_fetch_array($result)` and assign the fetched record to `$row`.

Also, do not forget to take out this line `$countRows=mysqli_affected_rows($db);` as you no longer need it.

Comment: Now I figured out how to make it work. I had to place $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql); right above the while sentence.